# How to swap the input from two text fields in HTML JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

When the button “Swap Text” is clicked, then the texts entered in the two text fields will be swapped. For example, if the user inputs "Craig" into the first text field, and "Kelly" in the second text field, once the button "Swap Text" is clicked, those two inputs will swap places.

Here is my code so far: (Any help would be greatly appreciated!)

```js
    function switchText(){
    var obj1 = document.getElementById("left");
    var obj2 = document.getElementById("right");

    var temp = obj1;
    obj1 = obj2;
    obj2 = temp;
    }

    function clearText(){
    document.getElementById('left').value = '';
    document.getElementById('right').value = '';
    }
```

```html
    <p><input type="text" id="left"/></p>

    <button onClick="switchText()">Switch</button>
    <button onClick="clearText()">Clear</button>

    <p><input type="text" id="right"/></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the value back to the inputs too. Its better to store the value of the input inside a variable than storing an entire object. After swapping the values call the `document.getElementById('left').value = obj1` to store the swapped value back to the input.

```js
    function switchText() {
      var obj1 = document.getElementById('left').value;
      var obj2 = document.getElementById('right').value;

      var temp = obj1;
      obj1 = obj2;
      obj2 = temp;
      
      // Save the swapped values to the input element.
      document.getElementById('left').value = obj1;
      document.getElementById('right').value = obj2;
    }
    
    function clearText(){
      document.getElementById('left').value = '';
      document.getElementById('right').value = '';
    }
```

```html
<p><input type="text" id="left"/></p>

    <button onClick="switchText()">Switch</button>
    <button onClick="clearText()">Clear</button>

    <p><input type="text" id="right"/></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to swap your input elements. You need to swap the value of your input elements.

Here is a working example:

```js
    function switchText(){
      let obj1 = document.getElementById("left");
      let obj2 = document.getElementById("right");
    
      let temp = obj1.value;
      obj1.value = obj2.value;
      obj2.value = temp;
    }
    
    function clearText(){
      document.getElementById('left').value = '';
      document.getElementById('right').value = '';
    }
```

```html
    <p><input type="text" id="left"/></p>
    
    <button onClick="switchText()">Switch</button>
    <button onClick="clearText()">Clear</button>
    
    <p><input type="text" id="right"/></p>
```